# Http Post in Flutter not Sending Headers

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to do a post request in Flutter

Below is the code

```
final String url = Urls.HOME_URL;
  String p = 'Bearer $vAuthToken';

  final Map<String, String> tokenData = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'Vauthtoken': p
  };

  final Map<String, String> data = {
    'classId': '4',
    'studentId': '5'
  };

  final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
      headers: tokenData,
      body: jsonEncode(data),
      encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);
  } else {
    print(response.body);
  }
```

However the header data is not working. I have the correct data and everything. This request works perfectly when done in Postman Client.
 Any one has any idea what is wrong?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check in postman whether your server accepts `vauthtoken` all lower case. If it does not it's a server bug. Dart lowercases all headers. The work around it it is a server bug is to use `http alt`.

Comment: Another problem is that you are setting a header specifying form data, but then encoding the body as JSON. Which is correct? As a screenshot of the postman request.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion @RichardHeap. Let me check those.

Comment: @Vipin have you solved this?  I am getting same problem

Comment: keys should always be in small letters.